# Can a C# Azure function create another thread?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Inside an Azure function I have to start a new thread and wait for its results by checking a status variable in a While loop. Once the thread completed its execution, the function will proceed to the end.

Is it a legitimate way of programming Azure functions?
What will happen to my function app if While loop doesn't break or a thread doesn't return?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can but you should use [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp) for this which are a set of premade libraries that were made specifically for such cases.

There are quite a few patterns that range from human intervention, orchestration and such.

Your code might look something like this as per their [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-external-events?tabs=csharp):

```
[FunctionName("BudgetApproval")]
public static async Task Run(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    bool approved = await context.WaitForExternalEvent<bool>("Approval");
    if (approved)
    {
        // approval granted - do the approved action
    }
    else
    {
        // approval denied - send a notification
    }
}
```

Or another option is you make a durable entity function that holds the state and then an event when that changes. Or a [monitor function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#monitoring) which basically loops around to see if state has changed. There are plenty of options